# How to apply Google Web Font Loader within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-webfonts, webfont-loader

I'm working on a piece of code that loads Google Fonts dynamically.

Some of the content of that page is loaded within an iframe (on the same domain origin). I'm struggling to load and apply the Web Fonts within the iframe. I have access to both the parent document and the iframe. Here is my code:

```
<h1>FONT to test</h1>
<p>Another FONT to test</p>

<iframe src="iframe-content.html"></iframe>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>

<script>
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: [ 'Abel' ]
        },

        fontactive: function() {
            $('h1').css('font-family', 'Abel');
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is the iframe contents code:

```
<h1>IFRAME FONT to test</h1>
<p>IFRAME Another FONT to test</p>
```

I tried using the "context" variable outlined here:
https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

But I didn't manage to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out this myself.

```
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: [ 'Abel' ]
    },
    context: window.frames[0].frameElement.contentWindow,
}
```

This will load the font in the document inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is essentially its own page so it cannot inherit anything from the page where the iframe tag lives.

If you add the styling code to *iframe-content.html* it should work. Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
<h1>IFRAME FONT to test</h1>
<p>IFRAME Another FONT to test</p>
<script>
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: [ 'Abel' ]
        },

        fontactive: function() {
            $('h1').css('font-family', 'Abel');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a way to influence this from the parent page? While I have access to iframe's code, I am only running my JS on the parent page. According to Google's documentation that I linked to (and if I understand it correctly), there should be a way of doing that, but I think I am missing something or just can't get it to work.

Comment: **Short answer: no**. There is no possible way to influence the content of an iframe from outside the code provided in the iframe's source. Iframes are isolated web content and cannot inherit anything from the page that contains the tag. What Google documentation are you referring to? The typekit Web Font Loader?

Comment: Yes. The "iframe" definition specifically, where they introduce the "context" method. In theory, I can replace the whole content of the iframe, but that's an ugly hack that might lead to complications, especially in a larger project.